# Automating incremental diffing and reintegration/patching

Tags: c#

I have data in one place (for the sake of simplicity let's say it's one zip file) and need to transfer it to some other place. Unfortunately I cannot use something like git repos in the two places with some common remote repo.

The scenario is that data never changes in both places at once. Changes are carried over from one place to the other - back and forth.

Still I do not want to transfer the whole file everytime. Since I do not want to implement my own incremental backup algorithm, I am wondering if I can leverage e.g. kdiff through some API from C# somehow to

- determine which bytes in the sequence have changed since the last "baseline"
- extract that information into a transport object
- incorporate the changes at the other place into the "old" byte sequence

What technology do you recommend?